# What is the meaning of VERBOSE,N-JOBS in decision tree and what is backend process of GRIDSEARCH CV?

Tags: decision-tree

I want explanation for the above mentioned terms.

I search many websites but I didn't got the meaning.

Comment: Where did you learn of these terms?

Comment: these are from decision tree algorithm from data science